# Deferred deep linking using FB AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to achieve deferred fb deferred deep linking. If app is not installed in device than on click of shared story in fb App, user can move on Google play store and can install App. All things are working fine.
But after installation if user open app first time through play store OPEN button.  AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent() method return targetUri null.

I am calling AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent() in on create method of Launcher Activity.

Note : If app is already installed than AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent() work fine and deeplinking works

Comment: I have used the AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent. But it not found in the latest facebook sdk 11.3.0. Any alternate solution?